# What should I do when project coding standards conflict with unit test code coverage?

Tags: php, coding-style, phpunit

I'm working on a personal project for the learning experience, and also at the same time to implement a decent body of code.  Part of this education, and making it a decent body of code, is unit testing.  I have recently dived into [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/automating-tests.html) and its code coverage tools.

I have encountered a situation with a particular implementation where the coding standard used causes code coverage to be lost.  In this particular instance breaking the coding standard used causes a jump from 88% to 94% in code coverage.

In a method I have two lines that look like the following:

```
    // .. some data validation stuff
    trigger_error('Error validating the stuff', E_USER_WARNING);
}
```

The data validation and the stuff isn't important here; the `}` is.  Right now, when the unit test goes over this line of code, a `PHPUnit_Framework_Error` is thrown on the line before the `}`, since the code never actually continues on to the end of the brace, this line is never captured by code coverage.

If I do

```
    // .. some data validation stuff
    trigger_error('Error validating the stuff', E_USER_WARNING);}
```

I get a 6% jump in code coverage.  I've tried setting `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning::$enabled` to `false`, but then I get an ugly, expected, error message in my terminal, since I want this project to eventually be used by people other than myself, error messages on unit tests are unacceptable.

In addition, I really would like for my coding styles to be implemented consistently.  The code-style violation would likely jump out upon further perusals of the code, meaning I'd also have to add a dreaded comment explaining why the braces were moved...likely in multiple places.

I guess my question(s) are:

1. Is there a setting for PHPUnit that would allow the [1TBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Variant:_1TBS_(OTBS)) to be used and still get covered by a test throwing an exception, or triggering an error, directly before a `}`?
2. Is it more important to follow the coding standard or get a boost in code coverage?  (Although the boost is really just the interpreter going over an extra `}`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't be obsessed with a number. You know that the numbers being reported are false and that you have more coverage than is being reported so why worry about it? It is more important that your tests cover all meaningful code than you achieve 100% code coverage.

If you feel the coding standard is important, and this one looks to be, then don't sacrifice readability for a number.

Answer (score 3):

To the original question:

Your coding guidelines shouldn't get into the way of just having 100% code coverage. **If you write your whole application in one line you get 100% but only because PHPUnit/xDebug currently report `LINE` coverage not `STATEMENT` coverage**.

---

For me the issue at hand is another one:

#### You have a method that unconditionally triggers an error at the end.

So you are not using exceptions. So maybe the question is:

`"Does trigger error get into the way of having 100% code coverage / complete tests"`

It doesn't. Usually trigger_error was used before exceptions where introduced or in projects staying consistent in their legacy use. Still php core functions trigger them but all those have return values to actually check for the error.

**So when using trigger_error it comes down to:**

- If you want to handle the error in the code use return values
- If you don't want to handle the error use logging and not trigger error

And if you have an return value you can write meaningful tests for that method.

One testcase that checks for the trigger_error and one test case (that calls the method with error suppression) that asserts on the return value.

Have a look at [**`Example 4.12 from the phpunit docs`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.errors)

---

#### For me this is a case where you see that something is wrong but the issue is not in the testing but in the code

You need to do something ugly in your tests and you start thinking about code coverage, coding rules and a "workaround". Usually when that happens to me I take a step back from the code and see if the issue can be solved on another level. Sometimes that leads to me discovering a design flaw in my code.

---

To get back to the question:

**The point in achieving 100% code coverage is that you have "clean code" not that you have 100% code coverage.** The whole point of striving for it is that you actually take a close look at your code and see why you can't reach lines of your code when using the class. That may be a design issue.

Fixing those flaws leads to an then easily achievable 100% coverage. Using hacks to just get "the number" right usually does worse than not caring at all. Not only to you not solve the issue you also cover it up.

Comment: From your answer it appears that I should have been using `error_log()` instead of `trigger_error()`.  Perhaps I was thinking about `trigger_error()` too much like a means to log information and not as much about the fact that it is really a mechanism in an entire error handling process.

Comment: Yeah, for logging there is `error_log()` or you applications log writer that you then can configure for production/dev usage and inject and mock out properly for the tests. I'd also advice to `trigger_error()` for anything that you can't fix in your code (like bad input data) as it will just clutter up your logfiles with information you don't/can't act on

Answer (score 2):

Your coverage error differential comes from PHPUnit and its related machinery computing code coverage in terms of "source lines".  There's nothing wrong with doing that way, if it can be done that way well.

Because the XDebug machinery only understands the line numbers of the lines it actually executes, I don't think it can "get it right" given that your style places "source lines" in places that it can't "execute".

Consider what happens if you write:

```
  1:   foo() {  return; 
  2:        ...1000 comment lines...
  1002:      }
```

What XDebug sees is the execution of the return at line 1, so one line is clearly covered (not quite true see example below); what PHPUnit sees (I think) is 1002 lines of code.  I think this will give you 0.1% coverage if run by itself.  (In larger programs, you're not likely to have such extreme code and the averages get better).

So the coverage you get, depends seriously on your coding style.  A more obscure variation:

```
  1:    bar() {   if (a) { $x=2; if (b) { $y=3 } } }
```

Since XDebug apparantly only tracks line numbers, if bar() is called, line 1 will be executed, and you have one line of source, so you'll get 100% coverage.  I beleive the graphics display tool will show the entire line as 'covered', too.  However, if the condition (a) is *false*,
the second conditional doesn't get a chance to be executed at all.  You could reasonably argue that only 50% of the code was covered (the first if but not the second).  And the graphics display is incorrect, since the $y=3 is shown as covered but is not, so you are mislead about the details.

To get a more accurate number, what the tool needs to know is the number of *separately controlled  executable blocks of code* (called "basic blocks" in the compiler literature), and the number of such blocks that got executed.   In the foo example, there's only one basic block, and if it gets executed, you should get 100% coverage of all basic blocks, and if not, you should zero percent, regardless of how you format your code.  In the bar example, there's two basic blocks (the function entry, and the $y=3 inside the second if), and you should get 50% coverage if the second block isn't executed, and 100% if it is, regardless of how it is formatted.

Since I don't think PHPUnit/XDebug have any understanding of basic blocks, I don't see how it can give the more accurate number.  (Statistically, they come fairly close; you said you were off by 6% and if your goal is to hit 80% you'll may have to hit 74-86% depending on your formatting to get 80% 'printed out" coverage.

The price you pay with the basic blocks solution, is that coverage is not in terms of "source lines", but rather in terms of executable blocks. I think the latter is more appropriate answer,
but your milage may vary, and bosses tend to be confused by the distinction.

Our [PHP Test Coverage tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/PHPTestCoverage.jsp) has this notion of basic blocks, obtained by doing a compiler-precise parse of your source code.  It will produce the more accurate numbers.  Its display tool also understands that you may have multiple statements in a line, and will color the executed and not-executed parts correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can have you cake and eat it too by using [ignore-code-coverage comments](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.ignoring-code-blocks) until Xdebug is improved to detect the `}` as non-executable.

```
    // .. some data validation stuff
    trigger_error('Error validating the stuff', E_USER_WARNING);
// @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
}
// @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
```

I submitted a feature request to add a single-line comment that would make it a little nicer on the eyes.

```
} // @codeCoverageIgnore
```

But perhaps you should follow stimms's advice and not get too worked up about reaching 100% coverage.