# Why does PHPUnit show some close-curly-braces as not being covered?

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I'm using PHPUnit 3.6.7, PHP_CodeCoverage 1.1.1, and Xdebug 2.1.2. When I have PHPUnit write my code coverage statistics to a clover-style XML file, it occasionally shows a close-curly-brace as not being covered by tests.

I see a lot of discussion online of when PHPUnit is "reaching" the close curly-braces, but I don't understand the general concept of what's going on. For example, I have zero coverage on one line here:

```
if (is_array($foo)) {
    foreach ($foo as $bar) {
        if (property_exists($bar, 'baz')) {
            return $bar;
        }
    }
}  // this line has 0 coverage
return null;
```

And here:

```
class Foo
{
    public $myProperty;
    public function myMethod()
    {
        $this->myProperty = '1';
    }
}  // this line has 0 coverage
```

Other classes in my project don't have this problem; their close-curly-braces don't show up in the XML file at all, so they are not listed as having zero coverage.

I understand that PHP_CodeCoverage 1.1.2 (not released yet) will let me put a "// @codeCoverageIgnore" comment after a close curly-brace, but until that's available I want to know what's going on, so that I can fix my tests to give me complete coverage. What's the rule-of-thumb to tell me when a curly-brace should be counted as "covered" or "not covered"?

Comment: Does it have 0 coverage, or does it say that there is no coverable code?

Comment: For the first case, do you have a test case covering $foo being an array but none of the entries in the array match the criteria?

Comment: Derick - the lines have 0 coverage; the XML says <line num="123" type="stmt" count="0"/>. Louis-Philippe: in the first example, I do not have a test case as you describe, but why should a lone close-curly-brace count as having any coverage?

Comment: Brian, if you provide the whole PHP file, I can (or you can) have a look with which code PHP sees with VLD (http://derickrethans.nl/projects.html#vld / http://pecl.php.net/package/vld).

Comment: @BrianKendig - It's not the closing brace that is runnable per se but rather that the block is exited by falling through. Use of `return`, `continue`, `break`, `throw`, etc. alter the regular flow of execution. In the first case Xdebug is detecting that you don't have a test case where the `for` loop runs through every element. See [Reaching 100% Code Coverage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804095/reaching-100-code-coverage-with-phpunit).

Comment: David - Thank you, but why would it be showing me 0 coverage on the closing brace of a class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's the rule-of-thumb to tell me when a curly-brace should be counted as "covered" or "not covered"?

There is a [**`"Edge Cases" section in the phpunit documentation`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.edge-cases) but that apparently isn't complete as I've learned in the last view days :)

What I've personally never seen is your second example failing. I also couldn't reproduce it: I couldn't find a PHP/xDebug/PHPUnit combination where this didn't work out. (Reproduce below)

The same goes for the other case you showed. For all I could test both closing braces where detected as "not executable/reachable" just like one would expect it.

So for both of those cases no //@codeCoverageIgnore or //@codeCoverageIgnore[Start|End] should be needed.

As @Derick suggested in the comments for any further analysis the whole file would be needed.

---

#### Reproduce

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public $myProperty;
    public function myMethod()
    {
        $this->myProperty = '1';
    }
}

<?php

require __DIR__ . '/closingBrace.php';

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testMyMethod() {
        $x = new Foo();
        $x->myMethod();
    }

}
```

Running `phpunit --coverage-text fooTest.php`

```
Code Coverage Report 
  2012-01-12 10:17:32

 Summary: 
  Classes: 100.00% (1/1)
  Methods: 100.00% (1/1)
  Lines:   100.00% (2/2)
```

which only marks the `$this->myProperty = '1';` it's closing brace as executable.

Comment: edorian, thank you very much; that helped me delve deeper into this. I've found that when I test a file like you did and add "--coverage-clover foo.xml", I get the correct results; but when I then add "--configuration=MyConfig.xml" to point it to my config file, the foo.xml file then shows the very last line of the file as a statement with 0 coverage. Even if I add a bunch of carriage-returns to pad the file out to 100 lines, it shows the 100th line as a statement with 0 coverage. I am looking into it, seeing if something is weird with my config file (there's not much in it).

Comment: @BrianKendig Edit the config into the question if you don't mind :)

Comment: @edorian I've had the same problem in the past. It turned out I had bad line endings ( like if I was encoding with Windows rather than Unix ). However now I am having this same problem again and can't diagnose why on ONE line of 900. Any new input since this was last answered?

Comment: I just noticed the other comment with the bug about returns right after the curly... but it was supposedly fixed and I'm on 2.2.2 so I'm further confused