# @codeCoverageIgnoreStart not working properly

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I need to coverage the following code:

```
switch($contract["value"]){

...
case "n":
     $contract["error_msg"] = "some Error";
     break;
...

default:
     $contract["error_msg"] = "Unexpected Error";
     break;
```

It's a switch that catches an error code and translates it to a message, but the default case is impossible to reproduce using automated tests, so I've tried to ignore this code from the code coverage report using the `@codeCoverageIgnoreStart` annotation, like this:

```
//@codeCoverageIgnoreStart
default:
    contract["error_msg"] = "Unexpected Error";
    break;
//@codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
```

But after runnig my tests, the annotation did not have any effect on report, and the lines kept uncoveraged.

[image]

How should I proceed with this situation?

Comment: `but the default case is impossible to reproduce by automated test` - It's not possible to unittest a switch statement? I think you're looking at (completely) the wrong problem.

Comment: i can't reproduce an error which i'm not expecting, all expected errors are handled in another method, returning a value to switch, so the default case is some case when the other method fail (don't have any idea why, or if its possible)

Comment: [mock objects](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html) exist primarily for this purpose. I don't now why `codeCoverageIgnoreStart` isn't working (you should add some evidence that that's the case e.g. [a screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804095/reaching-100-code-coverage-with-phpunit)) - but as I first said it's in your interest to _not_ do that and just test it. Alternatively, your unit tests aren't unit tests at all - which is another reason to refactor them.

Comment: stack overflows demands at least 10 reputation to post a screenshot

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/f0gyg82wx/

Comment: its from last sonar report, i've changed the position of the annotation to the question state after noticed its was not coveraging, but it didn't worked too

Comment: this is the actual state: http://postimg.org/image/5ovfvr91d/

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
```

Or you test

```
Default:
    //@codeCoverageIgnoreStart
    contract["error_msg"] = "Unexpected Error";
    //@codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
   break;
```

From http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.ignoring-code-blocks.examples.Sample.php

Comment: Don't forget to put your code in code blocks, otherwise your answer is unreadable.

Comment: sorry from the smartphohen don't see den Code