# Code coverage percentage and return

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, codeception

I run today Codeception with test coverage but what is strange for me if I have the following piece of code:

```
  return $created;
}
```

line with `}` is marked as `Dead code` so it is not counted for percentage in code coverage.

Question - should it work this way and what can I do to make it count for percentage in code coverage and not mark as `Dead code`.

Now I can have 2 files with 94% code coverage but one of them might be 100% code coverage because of those lines with just `}`

**EDIT**

I've just checked it and for the following code:

```
public function paginate(
    $perPage = 50,
    array $columns = ['*'],
    array $order = ['type', 'orderby', 'type_value']
) {
    return parent::paginate($perPage, $columns, $order);
}
```

everything is counted for percentage in code coverage. However still the list line `}` is marked as `Dead code`

Comment: Just wondering, if all your function body does is call it's parent, why are you defining it? Only to set different default values for $perPage, $columns and $order?

Furthermore check your versions of PHP, PHPUnit and Xdebug - it might be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804095/reaching-100-code-coverage-with-phpunit?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of collecting test coverage data the way it is traditionally done with PHP with XDEBUG.  XDEBUG captures the fact that a PHP statement has been executed by the PHP P-code engine.  "}" isn't a statement!  Thus the "lines covered" collected data doesn't include the "}" because it literally isn't executed.   It can get worse than your example; consider:

```
   public function foo() {
          if (...)  {
              return ...;
          }
          if (...)  {
              return ...;
          }
          ...
   }
```

The PHP execution engine doesn't "execute" any of the "}".  They are likely all marked as dead.

There are other PHP test coverage tools that associate test (branch) points explicitly with source code structures.  With that association, any covered (executed) test/branch point implicitly covers the corresponding code structures.  That would include the opening and closing braces of any block, including a function block... so the specific problem you have would not occur.  Capturing coverage data this way can be at finer grain than statements; consider the "x?y:z" operator.

Comment: @Ira Which tool do you use that covers this the best?  I have tried a couple, and am not decided yet on which to use, and could use some guidance, while also helping others that find this answer.

Comment: Not so much "use" as "provide".   Our PHP Test Coverage tool has the "nice" properties I describe above.   See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/PHPTestCoverage.html

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't focus too much on 100% code coverage. Having 100% code coverage doesn't mean your code is completely bug-free. Creating unit tests that make sense and *properly* test your code is much more important than just adding irrelevant tests or spending tons of time on rewriting your code only to get 100% code coverage.

Second, there is no way to answer your question without seeing more of your code. I'm making a big assumption here, but I assume your return statement is somewhere within a conditional block - and not at the end of a function. If so, an approach like this will probably 'solve' your issue

```
function returnTest($created) {

    if(!shouldThisMethodReturnCreated()) {
        $returnValue = false;
    } else {
        $returnValue = $created;
    }

    return $returnValue;
}
```

Comment: I've added more code. And it's counted for code coverage but is still marked as `Dead code`. Should it work this way?