# PHP Code Coverage of early exit in Generators with PHPUnit and XDebug

Tags: php, phpunit, generator, code-coverage, xdebug

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but I don't seem to be able to get 100% coverage with early exit inside a PHP 5.5 generator.

For example:

```
<?php

function gen($branch = false)
{
    yield;

    if($branch) {
        echo 'branched';
        return;
    } // This line is never covered.
    echo 'did not branch';

}
```

The closing bracket of the if statement is never covered. It's not considered "dead code", it behaves as though you didn't consider the possibility of exiting the if statement.

I don't want to use an `else` because, as phpmd would say, "else is never necessary", but I would like to get 100% coverage (as that makes it easy to see if I've missed something in new code without drilling down).

Has anyone else run into this? Is there a solution?

Comment: Closing brackets are always considered dead code. I believe this is a bug in the combination of PHP_CodeCoverage and XDebug. [This](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1869) guy seems to have success with downgrading PHP_CodeCoverage.

Comment: Also, just a side note, remember that `100 % code coverage !== fully tested code`, so coverage shouldn't be the only success criteria for your tests.

Comment: In this case the code is considered "uncovered" rather than "dead". Currently using `phpunit/php-code-coverage @ 2.2.4` and  it seems to be specific to generators so I don't think that it's the same problem. I reported the issue to both [php-code-coverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/392) and to [Xdebug](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1192). Hopefully they will be able to work it out. :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9142361/120163

Comment: Doesn't actually solve, or really address the problem at all. XDebug is perfectly capable of differentiating between Dead code and Uncovered. This issue seems specific to Generators as my methods all have 100% coverage. A windows only tool isn't appropriate for me. Additionally, I'd argue that 100% coverage is significantly important because 1) you can see *at a glance* something that's been added but not tested 2) [one of my projects](https://github.com/AyeAyeApi/Api), getting literally the last line of coverage (which really was just a `}`) revealed a critical bug I hadn't considered.

Comment: [Confirmed bug in Xdebug](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1192).Once resolved I'll close the question.

Comment: fixecd, i think it's safe to close https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1192#c3196 :-P

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @delboy1978uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug in Xdebug](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1192), and is resolved in [version 2.4.0](https://xdebug.org/updates.php#x_2_4_0beta1)